# Combine multiple function parameters into one in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to combine multiple function arguments/parameters into one in nodejs? For example:

```
var foo = “test1”
var bar = “test2”

var combined = foo,bar

function myFunction(input){

console.log(foo)
console.log(bar)
}

myFunction(combined)

//test1
//test2
```

Edit:
I’m trying to use this with shelljs-exec-proxy:

```
var shell = require('shelljs-exec-proxy')
var currentSourceLine = "/home/haveagitgat/Desktop/1/1'.mp4"
var currentDestinationLine = "/home/haveagitgat/Desktop/2/1'.mp4"


//Normally called like this 

shell.HandBrakeCLI('-i', currentSourceLine, '-o', currentDestinationLine, '-Z', 'Very Fast 1080p30');

//Would like to call with something like this

var combined = '-i', currentSourceLine, '-o', currentDestinationLine, '-Z', 'Very Fast 1080p30'


shell.HandBrakeCLI(combined);
```

Comment: Why not just pass an object in? You can use `{ foo, bar }` as the parameter to your function to get both foo and bar out.

Comment: @technogeek1995 thanks for the suggestion but I added more info in an edit as to why I don’t think I can do that.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to use an object, like:

```
var foo = "test1"
var bar = "test2"

var combined = {
   foo,
   bar
}

function myFunction(input){

console.log(input.foo)
console.log(input.bar)
}

myFunction(combined)
```

Edit: a solution to your edited question

```
var combined = ['-i', currentSourceLine, '-o', currentDestinationLine, '-Z', 'Very Fast 1080p30'] // This is an Array of arguments!
shell.HandBrakeCLI(...combined); // This uses argument destructuring
```

Comment: I’m trying to use shelljs-exec-proxy with one of my projects - I don’t have access to the inner workings of the function so I dont think I can use an object. E.g. the function would be shell.exec(foo,bar) normally but I’d like to be able pass in shell.exec(combined) so I don’t have to rewrite all of my other code.

Comment: The way to add multiple parameters would likely depend on the shell code you want to execute. I would suggest adding more information of this to your question.

Comment: @HaveAGitGat I have added a solution to your problem. Don't forget to @ someone so they get notified!

Comment: Thanks for that I'll try it now! And I tried '@' you twice on mobile but it didn't seem to work for some reason, must have been a temp bug or something.